# Showing that the two groups are isomorphic

Tags: abstract-algebra, modular-arithmetic, group-isomorphism

I need to show that the group $U_{16}$ is isomorphic to the group $\mathbf{Z_4} \times \mathbf{Z_2}$.

I could clearly write out the multiplication tables for the two groups and then find a mapping of each element from $U_{16}$ to each element of $\mathbf{Z_4} \times \mathbf{Z_2}$, but this seems like too many computations.  Since each group is of order $8$, their multiplication tables would each consist of $64$ computations, and seems like a boring way to do this problem.

Is there a smarter/more elegant way of doing so?

Also, since I am told that they are isomorphic, the two groups must share invariant properties, i.e., being abelian, being cyclic etc.

Thank you for your help and time!

Comment: Find an element of order $4$ in $U_{16}$ and then find an element of order $2$ that is not a power of that element of order $4$.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews So in $U_{16}$, the element 5 is of order 4, and also 9 is an element of order 2 which is not a power of that element.  I'm confused on how this shows that the two groups are isomorphic.

Comment: $5^2=9$ in $U_{16}$, so nope.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Ok. how about 5 being the element of order 4 and 7 being the element of order 2 that is not a power of 5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right that there are slicker ways to do this. Here's one sort of follow-your-nose approach:

You know that $U(16)$ consists of all (equivalence classes mod $16$ of) the odd integers $\{1,3,5,\ldots,15\}$, which is a set of order $8$. You can start by thinking about how different powers of a prime behave in this group. For instance, you can check $\langle 3 \rangle$ is a subgroup of order $4$, as is $\langle 5 \rangle$, and $\langle 7 \rangle$ is a subgroup of order $2$ that intersects the previous two subgroups trivially. This implies (why?) that, for instance, $\{3^m 7^n : 0\leq m \leq 3, 0 \leq n \leq 1\}$ is of order $8$, and that $(m,n) \mapsto 3^m7^n$ defines a surjective homomorphism $\mathbb Z_4 \times \mathbb Z_2 \to U(16)$.

Edit: Whoops! I missed the conversation in the comments. You've found an analogous argument using instead $(m,n) \mapsto 5^m 7^n$ instead.

Comment: I believe this is what Thomas Andrews was trying to convey to my simple brain.  A very interesting argument by the way.  Thank you for your help!!!

Comment: "You're write"?! This disturbs me deeply.

Comment: @SpamIAm: Dear god, me too! Thanks for spotting the typo!

Comment: @mathamphetamines Happy to be of assistance! And yes, this does appear to be what Thomas Andrews was helping you find in the comments.